# Load any site within an iframe using the browser webRequest API?

Tags: javascript, iframe, browser, http-headers

I'm developing a chrome extension where I need to load a webpage inside of an iframe. I can make some websites load within the iframe, but others have something blocking it. E.g. https://amazon.ca will load inside the iframe, but not https://shop.lululemon.com/.

Can I use the webRequest API to modify the headers and load the page? Or some other workaround?